# JS immutable objects keep the same object type

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability

Let's say I have a class.

```
class Test {

  constructor() {
        this.name = 'name';
        this.arr = [];
    }
}
```

And I need to create multiple instances from this class.

```
const entities = {
   1: new Test(),
   2: new Test()
}
```

Now, I need to update one of the properties in a shallow clone manner.

```
const newEntities = {
    ...entities,
    [1]: {
      ...entities[1],
      name: 'changed'
  }
}

console.log(newEntities[1].arr === entities[1].arr) <=== true
```

That's works, but the problem is that `[1]` is a simple object and not instance of `Test` anymore.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Property names and values of `entities` are not immutable as the question title suggests. Does this affect what you need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't keep instances using object destructuring so you'll need implement this behaviour.

**First example, set the new properties in the constructor:**

```
class Test {
  constructor(props) {
    props = props == null ? {} : props;

    this.name = 'name';
    this.arr = [];

    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
} 

const newEntities = {
  ...entities,
  [1]: new Test({ ...entities[1], name: 'changed' })
}
```

**Sencod example, use a custom method:**

```
class Test  {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'name';
    this.arr = [];
  }

  assign(props) {
    props = props == null ? {} : props;
    const instance = new Test();

    Object.assign(instance, this, props);

    return instance;
  }
} 

const newEntities = {
  ...entities,
  [1]: entities[1].assign({ name: 'changed' })
}
```

Comment: In your second example - newEntities[1]=== entities[1] ? true or false

Comment: It is false because the method is returning a new instance

Comment: You are creating the new instance but you are not keeping the rest of the properties. for example the arr.

Comment: I've just notice, I made a litle change

Comment: Looks better and in your first approach, you have not changed the name property.

Comment: I also wonder if in the second approach you don't have a memory leak. It seems that each time you called assign it saves a reference to the original object. ( by using the this keyword )

Comment: Fixed first example. It should not be any memory leak if Object.assign work as expected: "copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object". So the reference to the originial instance is no longer used

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) on your `[1]` object.

As result, it will be:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(newEntities[1], Test.prototype);
```

Comment: From MDN: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine.

Comment: Otherwise you can create a new object from prototype of Test `const newObj = Object.create(Test.prototype)` and merge it with your `[1]` object, but i'm not sure which way will be faster. 
I would prefer use this one, because it's more clearly. (If there is no any strict performance requirements or limitations).